# Adjusting installer to avoid admin rights

Tags: inno-setup

Here is a snippet of my installer script:

```
[run]
Filename: "{dotnet40}\regasm.exe"; Parameters: "MSAToolsLibrary_x86.dll /codebase"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; Flags: runhidden
Filename: "{dotnet4064}\regasm.exe"; Parameters: "MSAToolsLibrary_x64.dll /codebase"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; Flags: runhidden; Check: IsWin64
Filename: "{dotnet40}\regasm.exe"; \
    Parameters: "/u PTSTools_x86.dll"; \
    WorkingDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: runhidden; \
    Check: FileExists(ExpandConstant('{app}\PTSTools_x86.dll')); \
    AfterInstall: DoDeleteFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\PTSTools_x86.dll'))
Filename: "{dotnet4064}\regasm.exe"; \
    Parameters: "/u PTSTools_x64.dll"; \
    WorkingDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: runhidden; \
    Check: IsWin64 and FileExists(ExpandConstant('{app}\PTSTools_x64.dll')); \
    AfterInstall: DoDeleteFile(ExpandConstant('{app}\PTSTools_x64.dll'))

[UninstallRun]
Filename: {dotnet40}\regasm.exe; Parameters: /u MSAToolsLibrary_x86.dll; WorkingDir: {app}; Flags: runhidden
Filename: {dotnet4064}\regasm.exe; Parameters: /u MSAToolsLibrary_x64.dll; WorkingDir: {app}; Flags: runhidden; Check: IsWin64;

[Registry]
Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "Software\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "Software\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "AppPath"; ValueData: "{app}\MeetSchedAssist.exe"
```

It has recently been suggested to me that I adjust my installer so that admin privileges are not required. The reason being that the new warning about using `{userdesktop}` would go away (since I don't want to use `{commondesktop}`.

However, I had evelated the installer because of the above parts of my script. As far as I am aware they need to be run as an administrator.

I don't want to blow my program up for the sake of this issue. I am curious is there is a way to proceed without admin rights.

Comment: What "part" does need Administrator privileges? Don't the .dll work as intended, if they are not registered with Administrator privileges?

Comment: I understood that `regasm` required administrator rights. And access to `HKLM` or `HKLM64`

Comment: These DLL files need to be registered. You can't just run them.

Comment: I didn't try this myself, but check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11824559/850848